# adding images to options in select boostrap

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap, select

I'm making a language `select` and i can't get flags to display in `option` before the text.I'm using twitter bootstrap. Whys is that so? What method should i use to add them?

```
<select class="select form-control">
  <option>Lithuanian</option>
  <option>Russian</option>
</select>
```

I also made a simple sprite for the flags and made some classes to display them.

```
.flag {
  width: 16px;
  height: 11px;
  background:url(../img/flags.png) no-repeat
}

.flag.flag-lt {background-position: -16px 0}
.flag.flag-ru {background-position: 0 -11px}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to style standard `select` control in this way (I think because it's actually the OS that renders these controls not the browser).

I think your best option is to use Twitter Bootstrap's [Dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns) plugin which uses `ul` & `li` elements so you can style each item's contents how you please. You will need to use a hidden field & JavaScript to manage the selected value if you need to post the value back to the server.